# Angular - Share child component's variable with upper level components

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

My components are as shown below:

**user-app-component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-main-component></app-main-component>
```

**app-main-component.html**

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

In the **app-child** component, I receive data from an API, which I would like to be able to access inside the **app-header** component. Example shown below

**app-child.ts**

```
sharedApiData: any;

ngOnInit() {
  apiRequest.subscribe(response => {
    this.sharedApiData = response; // I want to access the 'sharedApiData' inside my app-header component
  })
}
```

Which is considered to be a "best practice" to achieve the scenario described? Using `EventEmitters`? Share the data using an `Injectable` service between the components? Any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a service with a BehaviorSubject to cache the value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180334/how-to-manage-service-member-initialization-with-data-retrieved-through-http-req/71182417#71182417

Comment: @GRD Is that way preferred than using a shared injectable service between the components and set/get a member variable of the service? If yes, why?

Comment: There is not any preferred way. Do as what best suited for your use case. Get/Set method called each time when change detection occurs. Subject way is good than get/set method. For more discussion please do connect by email. Thanks!